# Iterator start from first element

Tags: java, loops, iterator, hashset

I would like to call the first element of my Set 'set'. At this moment the content is set=["1", "2"]...When I run the following code, it return "2" in the iter.next(), is there a possibility that he returns first "1" and in the next loop "2"?

```
//Remove duplicates from array
Set set= new HashSet(Arrays.asList(leveranciers));

Iterator iter = set.iterator();

while (iter.hasNext()) {

    //for (Iterator it = set.iterator();it.hasNext();){
    PdfPTable table = GetTable(""+ iter.next());
    byte[] pdf = wdThis.wdGetAchatsIndirectController().GetPDFFromFolder("/intranetdocuments/docs/AchatsIndirect", table);
    wdThis.wdGetAchatsIndirectController().PrintPDF(pdf);
}
```

Comment: Off-topic, but you shouldn't use the raw type (without the type parameter) of any collection. That is, use `Set<MyType>` instead of `Set`.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are using a `Set`? Do you especially not want duplicates? If the order matters to you, consider changing your collection to a `List`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, a `HashSet` doesn't retain the insertion order. If you want that, use `LinkedHashSet`. And please use a parameterized version.

Comment: Do you know an alternative to loop through a Set?

Comment: You just want the first element? Then why are you creating a `Set`, rather than a `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is no 'first element' in a `Set`.  `set.iterator().next()` will give you an arbitrary element (or `null` if the set is empty).  `LinkedHashSet` will however let you iterate the elements in the order they were added to the set.  `TreeSet` will let you iterate the elements in their natural order (if they are `Comparable`).  Or perhaps you really want a `List`?

However, would this not do what you want?

```
// Assuming it is strings in 'leveranciers' (as implied by set=["1", "2"])
for(String s : Arrays.asList(leveranciers)) {
    PdfPTable table = GetTable("" + s);
    byte[] pdf = wdThis.wdGetAchatsIndirectController().GetPDFFromFolder("/intranetdocuments/docs/AchatsIndirect", table);
    wdThis.wdGetAchatsIndirectController().PrintPDF(pdf);
}
```

Also, as noted by Joffrey, please add in the generic types of your collections, as in `Foo`, `Bar` (whatever they might be) here:

```
Set<Foo> set = ...
Iterator<Bar> iter = ...
```